# how to correctly import and export modules in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having trouble with some basic module importing and exporting in react typescript. Exporting as follows:

```
//gameStateReducer.ts
import { Action, ActionKind, GameState } from './types';

export const gameStateReducer = (
  gameState: GameState,
  action: Action
): GameState => {

  //yada yada yada
};
```

and importing as:

```
//index.tsx
import { gameStateReducer } from './gameStateReducer';
```

The error message is:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./src/index.tsx 9:0-54

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './gameStateReducer' in '/Users/REDACTED/Documents/development/react-js/wordle/src'
```

This was all working when I was developing the same project on stackblitz, but trouble came when I began working locally with create-react-app.

I'm having the same problem with my constants module.

I've read typescript's reference page on exports and imports, and as a matter of fact, my types and interfaces are importing and exporting just fine.

I've tried importing and exporting to default with no luck.

Gotta be something simple I'm missing here. Thanks!

Comment: Are both in the same folder?

Comment: What's your tsconfig?

Comment: they are in the same folder. why, i have no tsconfig....

Comment: i followed these instructions: [link](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) to add typescript to my project.`npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

Comment: @kellys No tsconfig.json was the problem. I did not have typescript installed globally in npm. I installed it, then ran tsc --init to get the needed tsconfig.json file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way you added `import` this should work. I hope your directory structure is like

src

- gameStateReducer.ts
- index.ts

if your `gameStateReducer.ts` is under different directory then you should update import path to that directory.

for example, if you have structure like below

src

- anotherDirectory -> gameStateReducer.ts
- index.ts

then update `import` statement to this

`import { gameStateReducer } from './anotherDirectory/gameStateReducer';`